# Bypass TCP three way handshaking?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

Is it possible to make a system call or write a kernel module to craft a tcp connection right into ESTABLISHED state without going over the three way handshaking process, assuming the correct SYN-seq and ack number are provided dynamically?

Comment: How are you planning on even checking if the other side exists if you skip the whole handshake? It goes against the whole idea of TCP! If you want to do something like this you're better of writing your own protocol based on UDP which doesn't care if you have someone listening at the other end or not.

Comment: In my senerio, the client on the other side is going to be a controlled system which will send out packets using raw sockets.

Comment: Tcp-SessionHijacking will take over an exising connection, without establishing a complete 3 way handshake. That's the only thing, I can think of.

Comment: Part of the handshake protocol is there for security reasons. Using predetermined sequence numbers reduces security in that it makes TCP connections trivially spoofable ([this is what the infamous Kevin Mitnick did](http://wiki.cas.mcmaster.ca/index.php/The_Mitnick_attack)). If you don't want the overhead of TCP, then use UDP as @Nathilion says.

Comment: use `UDP` instead of `TCP` whole point of handshake is reliable connection. What if client `window size is different compare to server` you will see lots of packet drop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may like to have a look at [TCP fast open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Fast_Open), which modern Linux kernels implement:

> TCP Fast Open (TFO) is an extension to speed up the opening of successive Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) connections between two endpoints. It works by using a TFO cookie (a TCP option) in the initial SYN packet to authenticate a previously connected client. If successful, it may start sending data to the client before the receipt of the final ACK packet of the three way handshake is received, skipping a round trip and lowering the latency in the start of transmission of data.

Comment: This is enabled by default since Linux 3.13 (2014 Jan), so your computer is probably doing it already.

Comment: @Zaz It requires invoking `setsockopt(..., SOL_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN, ...)`. I just checked on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with `tcpdump` that neither `wget` nor Google Chrome use TCP fast open. What do you mean by _your computer is probably doing it already_?